# Is Object Detection Android app code available for ONNX/ORT object detection models?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I have a trained Object detection model in the ONNX format (optimized to run on mobile phones). I have converted that model into the ORT format (which is also a format that is optimized to run on mobile phones). In ONNX's website ([www.onnxruntime.ai](http://www.onnxruntime.ai)), there are links to github repositories containing iOS and Android code for example apps that use ORT models. But code is available only for Object Detection in iOS and Image Classification in Android. This is shown in the following link: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/mobile/

But, I want code for Object Detection app for Android. Is this developed and hosted anywhere such as github by either ONNX team or third parties? As far as I have searched I couldn't find any.

Any input will be helpful. Thank you.